# List attributes in weka tool

Tags: data-mining, weka

I was trying to preprocess weather.numeric.arff file in the weka explorer. I need to add list attributes to my file. Please tell me is there any way to apply these in my attributes. Thankyou.

Comment: By *list attributes* do you mean *nominal/categorical attributes* (attributes that have predefined labels rather than arbitrary numeric values)? If so, are you trying to convert existing numeric attributes into nominal ones or are you trying to add additional attributes?

Comment: @fracpete I just want to convert existing numeric attributes into nominal ones in my weka tool.

Comment: You can use the [NumericToNominal](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NumericToNominal.html) filter for that (package `weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute`). It just uses the string representation of the numbers as labels.